# PIG - Read each line into its field

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a way I can read each line from a logfile into its own field. I thought with ('\n') as a delimiter I should be able to achieve that.

File - *test*

```
Audit file /u01/app/oracle/admin/st01/adump/st011_ora_27063_1.aud
Node name:      test0041
CLIENT USER:[6] 'oracle'
```

So I would like to read this into three fields as

```
filename - Audit file /u01/app/oracle/admin/st01/adump/st011_ora_27063_1.aud
nodename - Node name:      test0041
username - CLIENT USER:[6] 'oracle'
```

I tried this but it didnt help.

```
A = LOAD 'test' using PigStorage ('\n') AS (filename, nodename, username);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use '\n' as a delimiter with PigStorage. According to the [Pig10 docs](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/func.html#pigstorage):

> Record Deliminters – For load statements Pig interprets the line feed ( '\n' ), carriage return ( '\r' or CTRL-M) and combined CR + LF ( '\r\n' ) characters as record delimiters (do not use these characters as field delimiters). For store statements Pig uses the line feed ('\n') character as the record delimiter.

If you want to parse the log file you'll have to write a custom loader.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is like that small, why don't you do a pre-processing of the file like converting \n to \t for example before LOAD?